# Ruby: Elegant way to write `if o.class == ClassA or o.class == ObjectB or o.class == ObjectC`

Tags: ruby, if-statement

Is there an elegant way to write

```
  if o.class == ClassA or o.class == ClassB or o.class == ClassC
```

I'm not specifically looking to compare classes, it was just an example where I wasn't doing things with booleans so I can't do something like

```
  if o.class == (ClassA or ClassB or ClassC)
```

Other examples are

```
  if string == "asdf" or string == "1337"
```

The only thing that I've found seems to be

```
  if [ClassA, ClassB, ClassC].include? o.class
```

or

```
  if ["asdf", "1337"].include? string
```

Comment: For the classes case, rather use Duck-Typing. What's wrong with the solution that you have found?

Comment: `include?` is what most people use in this case.

Comment: if you can subclass all ClassA, B, C to ClassSuper, you can do "if o.class < ClassSuper"

Comment: I'm for duck typing. Use if look_like_string.respond_to?(:to_s)

Comment: @texasbruce: A second for duck typing. It has a lot of benefits when you change your code later on.

Comment: @JonathanLeung Somewhat off-topic: Be careful using the `and` and `or` keywords. They're not really meant for `if` statements, and they can sometimes have unexpected issues of precedence.

Comment: Thanks, just read this: http://www.themomorohoax.com/2008/12/08/and-vs-amperand-in-ruby. Had gotten careless!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the most elegant solution is the one you already provided, which is using 'include?'.

Just for the sake of variety, you also have the option of using a case when:

```
case o
  when ClassA, ClassB, ClassC
  ...
```

Another alternative, which I believe is just a tad more readable than 'include?' is to create your own 'in?', for example:

```
class Object
  def in?(array)
    array.include? self
  end
end
```

and then you can use

```
if o.class.in? [ClassA, ClassB, ClassC]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `case`? It's not a terribly conventional use, but it sure is more elegant:

```
case o
when "asdf", "1337"
  puts "Hi!"
when Class1, Class2
  puts "Bye!"
end
```

Because `case` uses `===` which tests both equality and is a? relationships, and has a list syntax, it is very elegant for these kinds of situations.